# Shopify API rest client always returns latest Article record and ignores given handle criteria

Tags: node.js, typescript, shopify

```js
const articleResource = shopify.rest.Article.find({
    session,
    blog_id: myHardcodedBlogId,
    handle
}).then(response => {
    console.log({handle, response});
});
```

This piece of code always seems to return the latest created Article. I am pretty sure that this endpoint accepts the handle.

https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2023-10/resources/article#get-blogs-blog-id-articles

I tried to look at the request sent from the networks tab however I see no mention of the handle I have given it. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the singleton resource uri doesn't support all the properties of the collection resource.

https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2023-10/resources/article#get-blogs-blog-id-articles-article-id

If you query the collection with `.all` it should find it by `handle`.

```js
const articleResource = shopify.rest.Article.all({
    session,
    blog_id: myHardcodedBlogId,
    handle
}).then(response => {
    console.log({handle, response});
});
```